# How to insert data into local storage, when a local notification is shown?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification, flutter-workmanager, flutter-background

I'm working on an app that allows users to set reminders, which basically schedules local notifications. I have a feature in my app, that requires adding some data into the local database, whenever a notification is fired.

Let's say, a notification was scheduled for `5:00 PM on 13th March`, then it should add this time to the local database alongside the notification, without having to open the app.

Comment: put your function inside `workmanager` and execute workmanager callback when you receive the scheduled notification.

Comment: Should I schedule notification and `workmanager` at the same time to make it work?